# Text align not working with <span> tcpdf in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tcpdf

Using TCPDF without using the cell, I wanted to create column of item, quantity and price, but it is not working, I tried this code as per my research

```
    <span style="float:left">Item</span>
    <span style="text-align:center">Quantity</span>
    <div style="float:right">Amount</div>
```

this is the sample output

[image]

Comment: you have a spelling mistake. it should be `text-align: center`

Answer (score 1):

By defauld `span` have a display of `inline` so u will need to change the display to `block` and this should work.

```
    <span style="float: left; display: block; width: 100%;">Item</span>
    <span style="text-align: center; display: block; width: 100%;">Quantity</span>
    <div style="float: right; display: block;">Amount</div>
```